Creating Azure Entra groups that allows assignable roles
I have got some questions surrounding the creation of groups in Azure entra, I have the snippet of code below to create a group.
New-AzADGroup -DisplayName $groupfullname -SecurityEnabled $true -MailNickName $groupfullname
The problem with the snippet above is 2 fold. If I try to set the IsAssignable flag to true, it fails with an error A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'..
New-AzADGroup -DisplayName $groupfullname -SecurityEnabled $true -MailNickName $groupfullname -IsAssignableToRole $true
The current workaround that I have in place is this.
New-MgGroup -DisplayName $groupfullname -MailNickName $groupfullname -MailEnabled:$false -SecurityEnabled -IsAssignableToRole:$true
I would like to understand why New-AzADGroup fails or what I am doing incorrectly.

The reason it fails is because -MailEnabled, -SecurityEnabled and -IsAssignableToRole are switches not bool parameters, if you look at the cmdlet Syntax you'll see them as:
New-AzADGroup
    [-IsAssignableToRole]
    [-MailEnabled]
    [-SecurityEnabled]

Instead of:
New-AzADGroup
    [-IsAssignableToRole <bool>]
    [-MailEnabled <bool>]
    [-SecurityEnabled <bool>]

So for a switch param, if present means On or $true otherwise it's considered as Off or $false.
New-AzGroup -DisplayName $groupfullname -MailNickName $groupfullname -SecurityEnabled -IsAssignableToRole

Should be the proper call to create a group that is a Security Group and is Assignable to Roles that is NOT mail enabled.
